# Write concurrent in database windows phone 8.1 RT

Tags: database, sqlite, concurrency, windows-runtime

I'm developing app windows phone 8.1. I use SQLite to save data. But i can't write concurrent in database. It's exception "database is locked". I already have post blog to help about it. But, i see SQLite accept read concurrent, can't write concurrent. Anyone know formal different can write concurrent. or anyone used to develop Windows phone app 8.1 RT. What thing you use to save database ?